Can we use speech recognition functionality using microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk in lwc?
I know speech recognition is possible using Web Speech API, just wanted to check if this is possible using microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk in lightning component?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk

It seems to be possible, as it is stated in the home page:

The JavaScript versions of the Cognitive Services Speech SDK supports browser scenarios as well as the Node.js environment.

In theory, all it needs is to be compatible with Lightning Web Security to work. One would need to compile this TypeScript SDK to a JS bundle and import it in a component in Salesforce to test.
